# Указатель на член класса

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код. Почему при выводе i в 2 случаях выводится 1?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class AClass {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    void setAA(int a) { this->a = a; }
    void setBB(int b) { this->b = b; }
};

int main() {
    AClass a;
    a.a = 11;
    a.b = 22;
    int (AClass::*i);
    i = &AClass::a;
    std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a.*i=" << a.*i << std::endl;
    i = &AClass::b;
    std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a.*i=" << a.*i << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
i=1
a.*i=11
i=1
a.*i=22
```

Comment: Тут правда не метод класса, а поле. Но идея та же.

Comment: @user7860670, причем тут различия между printf и cout? Вопрос же о другом.

Comment: Ну printf тут действительно нет. А почему cout выводит 1 - там объясняется и приведен пример, как это делать правильно.

Comment: @user7860670, понятно, спасибо.